# Use JARs of linked projects instead of .class

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am building a desktop application with NetBeans 8.0.2. For my application, I have to manage 3 differents projects : The main project, and two "tool" projects that are linked to the main.

When I run the main project, it will check the JARs present in his classpath in order to retrieve the Manifest files and do some work with.

In order to have my application run correctly, it **has to see** the two linked projects' JARs but it doesn't, because NetBeans deals with the compiled classes of the project instead of the JAR (for debugging purposes I presume).

I found nothing about it on the Oracle documentation, and the only thing looking a bit like what I search is to create a big-fat-JAR by using another component.

Is there a way to tell NetBeans to "compile the linked projects and use the JARs instead of the .class" files ? Thanks in advance

EDIT : Here is an example when I add the project with "Add Project .." option

> /C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/GuiceProjectsRD/xxxReaderRef/build/classes/

And here is an example when I add the JAR

> /C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/JavaLib/xxxReaderRef.jar

When I add the JAR, I have the ".jar" extension which helps me identify a JAR and then look into it for a Manifest. When I add the Project, there is no path to the JAR but only to the compiled classes, and I can't work with that.

Comment: What do you mean by "it has to see the two linked projects' JARs"? If you use "Add project JARs" from the project settings (in the "libraries" category) of your main project, that doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it does work, but everytime I want to run my app, I have to clean/build the two other ones, go to the dist folder and link the new JAR to the main project. Isn't it possible to tell NetBeans to use directly the JAR of the linked project ?

Comment: That sounds like you chose "Add JAR/Folder" instead of "Add Project..." in the properties dialog. Try removing the JARs from the compile-time libraries, then add both projects using the "Add Project" button (the button in the dialog that opens then is "Add Project JAR files"). You can then also check "Track Java Dependencies" in the "Build/Compiling" category if that doesn't affect build times too much.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough .. Yes, I did choose "Add JAR/Folder" instead of "Add project..." because if I add the JAR, my application sees the JAR and is then able to get the Manifest from it. If I add the Project, my application sees only the path to the compiled classes. I will edit my question just to show an example.

Comment: Well, it's just that in my setup when I chose "Add Project" , the project JAR is added, not the class files.

Comment: Hm, I have checked "Build projects on Classpath" in the libraries category. Maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: I also have it checked, but it seems to be a configuration "issue". Thank you for your answer @Axel

Answer (score 1):

I would not depend on the Manifests in Jars since you then get this kind of issues.

Have a look at the [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) library. It's a small 100% pure Java library to work with Json/Hokon configuration.
Instead of relying on a Manifest, create a 'reference.conf' in each tool project. In your application, create an 'application.conf' (if needed). Load the config via 'ConfigFactory.load()'. It will automatically search all available reference.conf's, and application.conf, on the classpath, whether in a jar or not, and merge those configs into a single configuration.

I use this approach in project to be able to plugin extension. Have for example in tool A a configuration like

```
tool.A.class = 'my-tool-A.class'
```

or used nested structures like

```
tool {
  A {
    class = 'my-tool-A.class'
  }
}
```

Do something similar voor tool B.
Then in your application, from the Config, you can get a list of 'tool' configs and detect the available tools like that.

Comment: It seems to be a really interesting library, I will take a look thank you ! But as I stated, I just want to know if there is something we can do at the NetBeans level. If not, then I will rely on external libraries like yours.

Comment: It's not a Netbeans 'thing'. Any IDE will have the same issue.

Comment: So you're telling me there is no way to tell any IDE to use the created JAR instead of the build/classes/* files ?

Comment: Yes, I think the same issue exist in all IDE's (Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ) when you have java projects open in the same view. They'll all try to use the build classes and won't create a JAR on the fly because that just takes too much time. Compilation is smart and incremental nowadays. A small change and recompilation of a single class does not lead to a new jar being build.
But, it the problem is just to run the app, and not at compilation time, you might be able to define some 'pre-launch' steps to build the required jars. IntelliJ at least has an option for that.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your input @Joost, I will see if there is an option like you stated.